# Error attaching azureFile to kubernetes pod

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I'm trying to attach a volume to kubernetes pod but getting below error :

> error validating "test-pod.yaml": error validating data: found invalid
>   field azureFile for v1.Volume; if you choose to ignore these errors,
>   turn validation off with --validate=false

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.2", GitCommit:"3085895b8a70a3d985e9320a098e74f545546171", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.2", GitCommit:"3085895b8a70a3d985e9320a098e74f545546171", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes v1.1.2 doesn't support azureFile, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.1.2/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L203.

The earliest version that supports azureFile seems to be v1.2.0: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.2.0/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L263